# Could anyone help me fix this xpath expression?

Tags: xhtml, xpath

Time for another silly question :)

I got some tables in a xhtml-document with class="mytable" and inside those tables all sorts of elements, including `<input type="checkbox"/>` .. Now, I need to select all these checkboxes. I figured I'd use jquery with xpath, but my expression doesnt seem to work.

So far, I've come up with

```
$("table[class=mytable]//input[type=checkbox]")
```

.. but that doesnt seem to work :( Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Css selectors not xpath

```
$('table.mytable input[type="checkbox"]')
```

Comment: Yeah, guess that's easier :) Just wanted to try and fiddle with xpath, but I'll use css selectores instead. Thanks :)

Comment: @cwap: You can't use real XPath in a jQuery selector anyway.

Comment: @cwap no worries, sorry for not answering the question on xpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table[@class='mytable']//input[@type='checkbox']")
```

I think you need the @ symbol to target attributes and single quotes around the attribute values

Comment: Sadly that's not it :) As of jQuery 1.3+ you cannot use the @ in attribute selections. At least that what it states here: http://dev-tips.com/featured/jquery-tip-using-xpath-selectors . "As of jQuery 1.3, the attribute selector '@' has been deprectaed and will break in the latest version of jQuery. This is an easy fix, simply remove the @ selector". Besides, I can do selections just fine without the //. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: Oh wow.  How the heck can JQuery remove support for a basic XPath feature like that?  Using "@" to distinguish attribute children from element children has been a core feature of XPath queries for years before JQuery ever existed.  If they JQuery is saying that they no longer support the "@", it's like saying that you no longer support XPath, which seems bizarre